# Restarting apache reports success but apache service does not start

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I rebooted my server, but after I did the apache service will not start.

I can connect via ssh, and i type /etc/init.d/apache2 start

it says
starting web server apache2
...done

and even so, the service does not start!

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: Has this suddenly started happening, or has it always been like this? What have you done since you last remember it working?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `error.log` files on `/var/log/apache2`. The behavior you are seeing happens because apache likely died right after starting, the logs may have the information on why.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, I am trying to figure this out.  This is the relevant error message: `[Thu Apr 14 16:10:22 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Thu Apr 14 16:10:22 2011] [emerg] (2)No such file or directory: mod_fcgid: Can't create share memory for size %zu byte`

Comment: There you get your answer. :)